# PowerShell script to download files from a particular folder in blob storage container

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am writing a power shell script to download files from a azure blob storage container.The files are inside a folder in the container. The blob container structure looks like A>B>C.csv(Where A is my container). I want to download only C.csv to my local folder.
I wrote script as below.

```
    $AccountName = "X"
    $ContainerName = "A"
    $Key="dcg"
    $Context= New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AccountName -StorageAccountKey $Key
    $Files=Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName  -Context $Context -prefix "A/B"| 
     Where-Object {($_.ContentType -eq "application/octet-stream")}
    $DestinationPath = "D:\localfolder"
    $files |Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Destination $DestinationPath -Context $Context
```

But this script copy entire folder structure to my local folder. So my local folder contains
LocalFolder>A>B>C.csv, but I need only C.csv to be downloaded(LocalFolder>C.csv). Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to download the blob with out a folder structure using power shell script.
I tried the below script and getting the same output

```
$AccountName = "*******"
$ContainerName = "*******"
$BlobName = "*******" 
$localTargetDirectory ="*******"
$Key="*******"
$ctx= New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AccountName -StorageAccountKey $Key
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $BlobName -Container $ContainerName `
    -Destination $localTargetDirectory -Context $ctx
```

Other options we have is like azure storage explore and AZ copy to download the file directly with out folder structure.
here are the reference doc's [AZ Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download)
[Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows)